# Parameter is missing a value ssrs 2008

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a parameter of integer datatype which is hidden. When i run the report, report gives me an error

> Parameter X is missing a value

However if i make the parameter visible it works. I tried providing default value of 0 but that does not suffice my requirement as i have sub-report(Drill-dowm) depended on this parameter. Please help. Thanks!

Comment: Hmm? If you have a parameter that's both hidden *and* required you'd *have to* provide a value through some other means. If you are doing so, please extend your answer and tell us how you're doing that. Without that info we can't help you any further...

Answer (score 18):

Make sure that you have not specified Available Values for the parameter.  Available Values should be "None" for internal and hidden parameters.

Comment: The answer I was searching from last 2 days.

Comment: My report has been running like that for a couple weeks, but 'something' changed and removing available values did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I had to do an "if exists" statement for this to go away. It worked for me because it makes it always return a value even if that value is not need by my query.

```
    if exists (my select query)
    my select query
    else 
    select '2' 
    // '2' would never be used, but it made ssrs stop giving me
    // the stupid error and execute the rest of the query
```

Answer (score 6):

*First of all,*

Check that parameter's - **Available Values** by going to report parameters properties.

It must not be specified any values. So we should set it as **None**

*Second work around is,*

Just add a blank space at **Specify values** - in **Default values** inside report parameters properties.

This will surely work. Hope it will save your time.

Comment: What if the default value have to be retrieve from database (using dataset)? set Available Values to None doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

If you specify available values from query, then default values must be in list of available values. Default value in (Available) = true.

Answer (score 2):

The problem occurs also, if you have a parameter that depends of another one without "default value" inside the Dataset Query and does not admit null value.

For example:

**Parameter 1** have a default value: NameEmployee from the dataset "EmployeeSearch"

But the dataset "EmployeeSearch" have a filter or a parameter inside the query named @Month that indicate the number of the month. So if the value of @Month is null, SSRS will say "Parameter is missing a value".

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you had the same issue as I had, trying to run the report on a web page using a ReportViewer component, I managed to fix that issue by adding a `null` parameter before rendering the report:

**C# code:**

```
var parameters = new List<ReportParameter>();
parameters.Add(new ReportParameter("ParameterName", (string)null));
ReportViewer1.ServerReport.SetParameters(parameters);
```

Hope that will help

Answer (score 1):

Just need to add 1 default value to get around this error (even though that default value will never be used).

-Under "Report Parameter Properties" for that specific parameter, go to the Default Values page.

-Toggle "Specify values"

-Add a value (I added: "just_a_filler_to_get_around_hidden_value_error" so when I look back at it later I remember why I did such a thing)

-click OK

Answer (score 0):

I want to add to dmbreth's CORRECT answer.

I was missing the concept that the value of the parameter still needed to be tied to something. Originally, I was tying the output of a dataset by using the Available values portion of the parameter properties, but according to dmbreth's answer, that could not be the case. Finally I moved my output dependence settings from the **Available** Values section to the **Default** Values section and that did the trick.

So, in summary, in the parameter properties dialogue:

General Page - Allow multiple values checked(this option is specific to my application), parameter visibility set to internal

Available Values Page - None

Default Values Page - Get values from query, [appropriate dataset, value here]

Advanced Page - No significance here

Hopefully, that is clear enough to benefit someone else with the same problem...

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue where the default value as set by SSRS is `(Null)`, I didn't need the parameter for my report however; I found it useful for testing to filter down the list so I kept it, I guess I could have deleted it in SSRS on the dataset config. but I changed it to `=System.DBNull.Value` (I guess this could be any expression) instead and that worked for me, so then I can still pass in a value if need be and also set Available values (had to make sure a NULL value was added to my dataset) if I then decide to unhide at a later date.

Answer (score 0):

There is one other potential here. I have had a situation where the report designer works but the server report object does not. The solution is to delete the server object and then re-save it from the designer.