# Parameter x is missing a value bids 2008

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, dynamics-crm-2011, bids

I created a new report for an overview of a company. I added a report parameter, which default value is determined by query. But if I run the report and this query returns no results, I get the error "Parameter x is missing a value."

I found this post [Parameter is missing a value ssrs 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11168738/parameter-is-missing-a-value-ssrs-2008). But setting the available values to none didn't solved my problem. I allowed empty and null values too.

If I make the parameter visible everything is okay, I can choose a value or not and it works.

My parameter has following settings: 
Type: text
Allow empty values: true
Allow null values: true
Allow multiple values: false

Parameter visibility: Hidden

Available values: none

Default values: Get values from a query (this query sometimes has no results)

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a glitch with SSRS.

From [this MSDN blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/axsupport/archive/2012/11/20/quot-parameter-is-missing-a-value-quot-error-running-a-customized-report-in-microsoft-dynamics-ax-2012.aspx):

> Force the update of the properties by renaming the parameter
>
> 1. Open the report for editing in Visual Studio.
> 2. Expand the Parameters node and rename the affected parameter to ParameterName1.
> 3. Set Allow Blank and Nullable to True if not already set.
> 4. Deploy the report.
> 5. Rename the parameter back to ParameterName.
> 6. Deploy the report.