# SSRS Fetchxml SubReport shows error when no Data is returned

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, microsoft-dynamics, ssrs-tablix, fetchxml

I have a Main report and Sub Report. Passing parameter from Main Report to sub report,Sometimes Sub report have no Data and then my Sub Report shows error on main Report.
When there is data from Sub report it is properly displayed.

I have read few threads regarding same issue. But most of them stated using Dummy Data set. For dummy Data set SQL was used. I am using Fetchxml. Does anyone have Idea how to achieve this.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Error I receive:Error: Sub report could not be shown.

FYI, If I run Sub report Separately with Parameter passing manually and if there is no data retrieved still then it shows Error.

If there is data, then no issues.

Comment: When you execute the sub-report separately, what error do you get? Where are you running the report? If you're within Visual Studio, there may be messages in the Output window

Comment: Only Executing Subreport gives "The expected parameter for the report was not provided." I am running Report on Dynamics CRM application.

Comment: You probably have a hidden or system parameter (possibly a CRM Parameter) that you are not setting from the parent report. Can you list all your sub-report parameters?

Comment: I believe, I narrowed down the issue. Let me try explaining it. In SubReport
DataSet1 returns Rows or No Rows.
Parameter "salesID" has default value coming from DataSet1(SubReport).
Now if Dataset1 has Rows then good enough,"salesID" parameter behaves corretly, but if Dataset1 has no Rows returning then ,"salesID" parameter is the one causing issue.
Below are 2 links for stackoverflow with related solution but I m not sure how to use that in Fetchxml
srs-2008]

Comment: Links for Reference.

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17151353/how-to-handle-a-parameter-that-has-no-value-in-ssrs]

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11168738/parameter-is-missing-a-value-ssrs-2008]